# Symfony2 Form with Doctrine Entity type array

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity (Group) that has a data array (UserDisplayNames) (user_id => DisplayName) stored in it (A user can have different display name for different groups).

I'm looking for the best way to do a symfony2 form (in Sonata AdminBundle) which allows the key (user_id and value to be edited).

E.G.

```
Key <input type="text" name="key[]" value="{key}">
Value <input type="text" name="value[]" value="{value}">

Key <input type="text" name="key[]" value="{key}">
Value <input type="text" name="value[]" value="{value}">
```